# Is it possible to launch my APP after the selected text is copied on iOS or macOS system?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Like “Tap to Translate” of Google's Translate on Android, once you copy the selected text, the translate button will pop up. Click the button then Google's APP will show.

The feature seems happen only on Android system, but I don't know whether iOS or macOS can do so or not. So is it possible to launch my APP after the selected text is copied on iOS or macOS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in build solution for it. But you can build your own system.

Customise the menu options and add one extra menu i.e. translate and the translate it using your own logic or also can use some 3rd party API for translate if available.

For customise menu : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html

Google translate API : https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text

**Updating according to comments**

You can use share extension. Hope apple will give access for menu extension in future :)

Comment: Hello. The customized menu options you suggested (UIMenuController) can only be used in my APP, but I hope all of the APPs can show my customized menu options when the text is selected.  Is it possible to make all of the APPs show my menu options whatever the text is selected?

Comment: then you can use share extension. Hope apple will give access for menu extension in future :)

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**

Short Answer : **NO**
Because this type of features does not provided by Apple as like Android.
So best way to stop fight with it to find.

**For OS X :** Really I don't know about it.